# How to add sub-menus to Magento admin dashboard in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, admin, overrides

How to add sub-menu to Magento admin dashboard in **Magento 2.2.5?** I need to override the vendor file.

Refer my Screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This code is working fine I can able to create sub menu under Dashboard

Comment: I can able to create multiple sub menus under "Dashboard" Menu

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148401)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way:

app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <update id="Magento_Backend::dashboard" title="Dashboard" translate="title" module="Magento_Backend" sortOrder="10" resource="Magento_Backend::dashboard"/>
        <add id="Magento_Backend::dashboard_sub" title="Dashboard" translate="title" module="Magento_Backend" sortOrder="10" parent="Magento_Backend::dashboard" action="adminhtml/dashboard" resource="Magento_Backend::dashboard"/>
        <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_page_new" title="Pages" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="0" parent="Magento_Backend::dashboard" action="cms/page" resource="Magento_Cms::page"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: okay Sohel, sure I will try this and let you know.